# how can i make an excel graph of this data (two)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

```
 Mean ± SD baseline        Mean ± SD Final
 56.7 ± 6               
   84 ± 14                   82 ± 13
   34 ± 5                    33 ± 4.5
42.79 ± 3.19              40.45 ± 3.48
46.75 ± 9.64              47.76 ± 10.4
11.61 ± 2.06              10.76 ± 1.78
```

Comment: okay, but there are many types of graphs - and the usage of these will depend on the context.

Comment: please, any graph with bars would be appropriate.

Comment: Hi, you can make a graph with values either + or with -. Not with both. See if you can manually plot 1 +/-3 with 2+/-3. You cannot. Either you have to plot 1+3=4 against 2+3=5 or 1-3=-2 against 2-3=-1.

Comment: Why does this question have 4 down votes?

Comment: @Jon Peltier - Probably because the question doesn't describe what aspect of the data to illustrate.  Just providing a bunch of data and asking how to graph it is nebulous.  The question made intuitive sense to me because I'm used to seeing data like that, but it wouldn't necessarily be obvious to someone else.  Plus, being so open ended, people will interpret the requirements differently, and it would lead to bad answers and people wasting time in an effort to help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compare how both the mean and SD changed between baseline and final.  One way to illustrate what is in the table would be with the type of hi/lo chart used for stocks.  Create a table with mean, high (mean+SD), and low (mean-SD).  The rows in your table would be the categories and the columns would be the data series.  This [link](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/StockChartsAndLineChartTricks.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Put mean in a column, and SD in the next. Plot the first column as values in a line or XY chart, then add custom error bars with the SD values as both plus and minus error bar values.